# get futures from stream one by one

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a stream returning values from a web api and a widget that presents one value (using FutureBuilder). The user can iterate through the values with a simple next button. I don't want to load all values in advance but I don't want that each value will be loaded when pressing the next button.

my current code is:

```
Queue<Item> itemQueue = Queue<Item>();
Future<Item> curItem;

Future<Item> getItem() async {
  while (itemQueue.isEmpty)
    await Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: 250));
  return itemQueue.removeFirst();
}

@override
void initState() {
  // ...
  final sub = stream.listen((item) async {
    itemQueue.add(item);
  });
  // ...
}

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  // ...
  ItemWidget(curItem)
  // ...
  RaisedButton(child: Text("next"),
        onPressed: (){
          setState(() {
            curItem = getItem();
          });
        },)
  // ...
}
```

this works but feels like it's not the most correct/elegant way of doing this.

is there a better way?

thanks!

Comment: Does the stream contain all of the values you'll need or does listening to it result in additional requests being made?

Comment: it's a stream wrapper of a pagination object so additional requests are being made

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EDIT**:

As pointed out in the comments, the original answer of creating a broadcast stream may result in events being dropped on the floor. To avoid creating a broadcast stream, we can use [StreamIterator](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.5.1/dart-async/StreamIterator-class.html) to  iterate through the stream one element at a time:

```dart
final myStream = Stream.fromIterable([1,2,3,4,5]);

// We need to be able to listen to the stream multiple times.
final iter = StreamIterator(myStream);

// The iterator doesn't start at the first element, so we need to
// do that ourselves.
while (await iter.moveNext()) {
  // StreamIterator.current will always point to the currently selected
  // element of the stream.
  print(iter.current);
}
```

**ORIGINAL:**
You should be able to utilize [Stream.asBroadcastStream](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.7.1/dart-async/Stream/asBroadcastStream.html) and [Stream.take](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.7.1/dart-async/Stream/take.html) to do this.

Your code would look something like this:

```dart
final myStream = Stream.fromIterable([1,2,3,4,5]);

// We need to be able to listen to the stream multiple times.
final stream = myStream.asBroadcastStream();

for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
  // Creates a new Stream with 1 element which we can call Stream.first on
  // This also changes the contents of stream.
  print(await stream.take(1).first);
}
```

Which would output:

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

Comment: that may work in your example but in my case between the clicks on the next button the stream is left unlistened and items are being thrown away

Comment: Ah, I forgot how broadcast streams behave... sorry about that. Check out my edit which should work and happens to be much cleaner.

Comment: The StreamIterator works for me, and I think it's absolutely the appropriate way to do the job. Thanks a lot, you saved me hours of struggling.